# How to concatenate multiple values in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello folks I have a question regarding the concatenation of multiple values which are coming into the single column separated with comma like below.

For example There is a report which is fetching data but for one column there are 5 values so due to that 5 times the same line is repeating for all columns so I want to concatenate all the 5 values for that particular column.

please let me know how can i do that.
below is the query which is fetching 5 values and I want those values into one row only separated by comma.

```
SELECT PAC.PACKAGED_ITEM_GID 
FROM SHIPMENT SH, ORDER_MOVEMENT OM, 
   ORDER_MOVEMENT_D OMD, S_SHIP_UNIT SSU, S_SHIP_UNIT_LINE SUL, 
   PACKAGED_ITEM PAC
WHERE OM.SHIPMENT_GID = SH.SHIPMENT_GID 
AND OM.ORDER_MOVEMENT_GID = OMD.ORDER_MOVEMENT_GID 
AND OMD.S_SHIP_UNIT_GID = SSU.S_SHIP_UNIT_GID 
AND SSU.S_SHIP_UNIT_GID=SUL.S_SHIP_UNIT_GID 
AND SUL.PACKAGED_ITEM_GID = PAC.PACKAGED_ITEM_GID 
AND SH.SHIPMENT_GID = 'ULA/SAO.5000070143'
```

Comment: `SELECT PAC.PACKAGED_ITEM_GID FROM SHIPMENT SH, ORDER_MOVEMENT OM, ORDER_MOVEMENT_D OMD, S_SHIP_UNIT SSU, S_SHIP_UNIT_LINE SUL, PACKAGED_ITEM PAC
WHERE OM.SHIPMENT_GID = SH.SHIPMENT_GID 
AND OM.ORDER_MOVEMENT_GID = OMD.ORDER_MOVEMENT_GID 
AND OMD.S_SHIP_UNIT_GID = SSU.S_SHIP_UNIT_GID 
AND SSU.S_SHIP_UNIT_GID=SUL.S_SHIP_UNIT_GID 
AND SUL.PACKAGED_ITEM_GID = PAC.PACKAGED_ITEM_GID
AND SH.SHIPMENT_GID = 'ULA/SAO.5000070143'

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and the query you are using *in the text of the question*.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it but i got it:)

Comment: SELECT  LISTAGG(PAC.PACKAGED_ITEM_GID , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PAC.PACKAGED_ITEM_GID) FROM SHIPMENT SH, ORDER_MOVEMENT OM, ORDER_MOVEMENT_D OMD, S_SHIP_UNIT SSU, S_SHIP_UNIT_LINE SUL, PACKAGED_ITEM PAC
WHERE OM.SHIPMENT_GID = SH.SHIPMENT_GID 
AND OM.ORDER_MOVEMENT_GID = OMD.ORDER_MOVEMENT_GID 
AND OMD.S_SHIP_UNIT_GID = SSU.S_SHIP_UNIT_GID 
AND SSU.S_SHIP_UNIT_GID=SUL.S_SHIP_UNIT_GID 
AND SUL.PACKAGED_ITEM_GID = PAC.PACKAGED_ITEM_GID
AND SH.SHIPMENT_GID = 'ULA/SAO.5000070143'

Comment: @otm notifications: Why these queries in the comment section? The last query is for Oracle. It doesn't work in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's string aggregation function is `GROUP_CONCAT`.

You are using a join syntax that was used in the 1980's. Why? Where and when did you learn that? Use proper ANSI joins instead:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pac.packaged_item_gid) AS packaged_item_gids
FROM shipment sh
JOIN order_movement    om   ON  om.shipment_gid = sh.shipment_gid 
JOIN order_movement_d  omd  ON  omd.order_movement_gid = om.order_movement_gid
JOIN s_ship_unit       ssu  ON  ssu.s_ship_unit_gid = omd.s_ship_unit_gid
JOIN s_ship_unit_line  sul  ON  sul.s_ship_unit_gid = ssu.s_ship_unit_gid
JOIN packaged_item     pac  ON  pac.packaged_item_gid = sul.packaged_item_gid
WHERE sh.shipment_gid = 'ula/sao.5000070143';
```

As you are selecting the `packaged_item_gid` only, which is available in `s_ship_unit_line`, you can select from this table alone and look up matching shipments in an `IN` clause.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(packaged_item_gid) as packaged_item_gids
FROM s_ship_unit_line
WHERE s_ship_unit_gid in 
(
  select ssu.s_ship_unit_gid
  FROM shipment sh
  JOIN order_movement    om   ON  om.shipment_gid = sh.shipment_gid 
  JOIN order_movement_d  omd  ON  omd.order_movement_gid = om.order_movement_gid
  JOIN s_ship_unit       ssu  ON  ssu.s_ship_unit_gid = omd.s_ship_unit_gid
  WHERE sh.shipment_gid = 'ula/sao.5000070143'
);
```